# AAD Powershell - resource does not exist

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Sorry for asking newbie questions, but I am trying to pull some basic data of AAD using a prepared CSV with the users that I need the info about.

```
   $DomainNames = Import-CSV -Path C:\PS\CEPS.csv
   ForEach ($DomainName in $DomainNames) {
      Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $DomainName | Select-Object DisplayName
      }
      Export-CSV -Path C:\PS\licenses01122021\group1.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

I get this error: Message: Resource '@{DomainName=X@X.x}' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Comment: No such thing as a "newbie question" as long as the one asking has done it's fair share of research. By the looks of the error message, seems like you just need to reference the `DomainName` column from your Csv, so: `-ObjectId $DomainName.DomainName`.

Comment: Oh my god I am blind. Thank you very much!

Comment: But now I have a different problem, Export-CSV does not spit out anything, it displays it in the terminal. Perfectly, I would want to get the values from each user printed in separate rows, they could be delimited with anything. But it's not possible to keep such script short, isn't it?

Comment: Then remove `| Select-Object DisplayName` because you are throwing away all other properties by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply meant that you were passing an object to the `ObjectId` parameter of the cmdlet, to fix this, you just need to reference the property `DomainName` of your object (`DomainName` being the column name of your Csv). As for the second question in comment, you're never storing the result of your loop to a variable hence why you see the result on the console. If you want to do all the process on one pipeline, you could use `ForEach-Object` instead:

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\PS\CEPS.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $_.DomainName
} | Select-Object DisplayName |
Export-CSV -Path C:\PS\licenses01122021\group1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`-Delimiter ","` is not needed as it's the default value for this parameter.